# javascript Error: Why I cannot clone/copy a tag from "li" to "table"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, clone

I want to drag a `<li>` from a list and drop it to a `<td>` in a table and duplicate the value.

Drag is perfectly done, however it's not coping, just cutting. I want to copy/clone the tag. I tried this piece of code but it's not working.

```
 var dataM = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 var clone = dataM.cloneNode(true);
 document.getElementById("fri11").appendChild(document.getElementById(clone));
```

```js
//For drag and drop
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));


  //to know the drop activity
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element was dropped.";

  //to know the table specific area Id and data
  var newdata = ev.target.id;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "" + newdata;
  document.getElementById("demo11").innerHTML = "" + document.getElementById(newdata);

  //to know the course list specific area Id and data
  var newdata1 = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "" + newdata1;
  document.getElementById("demo22").innerHTML = "" + document.getElementById(newdata1);


  //cut perfectly done  !!!!but its not coping, just cutting :(
  // var dataM = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  // document.getElementById("fri11").appendChild(document.getElementById(dataM));

  //I tried this piece of code but it's not working.
  var dataM = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var clone = dataM.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("fri11").appendChild(document.getElementById(clone));
}
```

```css
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- this is part of the table -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11:20am-12:50pm</td>
    <td id="sat11" value="s" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    <td id="sun11" value="s" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    <td id="mon11" value="s" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    <td id="tue11" value="s" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    <td id="wed11" value="s" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    <td id="thu11" value="s" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    <td id="fri11" value="s" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>



<!-- this is part of the list -->
<ul id="myUL">
  <li id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">CSE115</li>
  <li id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">CSE173</li>
  <li id="drag3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">CSE215</li>
  <li id="drag4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">CSE225</li>
  <li id="drag5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">CSE231</li>
  <li id="drag6" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">CSE299</li>
  <li id="drag7" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">CSE311</li>
  <li id="drag8" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">CSE327</li>
  <li id="drag9" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">CSE332</li>
  <li id="drag10" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">CSE323</li>
</ul>
```

https://ibb.co/NWzXdtt
Actually, I want this

I have 2 things: one table and one list. I want to drag a list item `<li>` from a list and put it into a table. Everything is OK but I want to duplicate/clone the tag (like, when I drop a tag/list/data to the table id `sun11` it's automatically cloned to the table id `fri11`) in one other box in the table when I drop the element/tag from the list. I tried to clone it but it's not working. I thinking the main problem in line 36 in JavaScript. but I cannot clone the data/tag.

Comment: You aren't doing any cloning - you are *moving* the HTML element entirely to a new location.

Comment: You are not using clone correctly. https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-clonenode, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode). `Node.cloneNode` returns a node, you are passing the result to `getElementById` which expects a string, not a node.

Comment: Also you aren't using jQuery at all in your example but your question is tagged jQuery. Do you actually have jQuery available to use?

Comment: I will use jquary in another field. sorry for the tag. and please give me a suggestion code for a copy this. @Marie

Comment: @Md.MarufBillah codepen added to answer.

Comment: Everything is ok. Thanks to almighty and @yayapro. But here is a problem. when I drag my list items `<li>` back again to the list `<ul>` then it is not working.  `<if (ev.target.closest('td').querySelector('li')) return;>` this piece of code is using for more than one list element `<li>` cannot be able to drag in the table `<td>` but here the problem is now, I won't be able to re back my list element  `<li>` to the course list `<ul>`. anyone?? who can help me? here is the codepen link [here is the codepen link](https://codepen.io/maruf1020/pen/KLjRaN)

Comment: @Md.MarufBillah change it to : `if(ev.target.id != 'myUL' && ev.target.closest('td').querySelector('li'))` (https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/QRemEJ?editors=0010)

Comment: @Md.MarufBillah also if you want to let user drop everywhere on choice panel, do this: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/VOoRyW?editors=0010 (line 36 and 135 on new file are changes)

Comment: in the last 2 days, I am learning javascript from w3school. I understand I need to know a lot of things. I'm really proud of u and I feel shame also. You are a great programmer. now I have done my project like this [codepen link](https://codepen.io/maruf1020/pen/KjPVgp?editors=0010) and I tried to change the code pattern for some beauty. I see in your last codepen link. the code is awesome.it works very well. I drop courses form table to anywhere on the list. I want this but my code pattern is now changed. what should I do now? please, can you check my new code?

Comment: @yayapro I set some `functions` in `drag function` I also upload it on the web. the web link is [web link](https://catherineflonwelcomecenter.org/Maruf-NSU/). I am working on the database 'mysql' right now. I also have a problem but I ignore it. some of the courses should take only one box of the table `no clone for them`. but I skipped it. I tried much time but I am not good at javascript, that's why I cannot do it. and I don't wanna pain you again so, I didn't tell you to help me. but I badly need some help.

Comment: @Md.MarufBillah Hi again. how are you? actually your project is not a simple project, so its problems are not 1 or 2 .just don't scare from javascript, and start learning it. currently i work on some projects , they involve alot of technologies (more that 10) ,and i just learn and do them. you don't need help, you should just start learning it.

Comment: @Md.MarufBillah i read your prev comment now. glad you started learning js. don't miss lynda and udemy also. by the way, i had time and did this. but please don't expect me doing this in future. i added two things you mentioned. changed lines in this file are: (35,70,71,77,78). (change lines 77,78 to what you want. it prevent clone for specific courses.) https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/ZdzQZJ?editors=0010

Comment: Alhamdulillah, I am fine, brother. How are you? yes, brother, you are right. This is not a simple project. This is a big project. My semester is starting today. I was hopeful that this will be a good project for my current course(junior designing CSE299). but my faculty told me today "this was my masters' project and it's too complicated. you cannot complete the whole project over this semester".  I was trying to convince him to do this project but he didn't accept my request. he told me to create a not statistic webpage with a few simple applications. Think, how sad this for me?

Comment: I am learning CSS, HTML, javascript, database in only 20 days on my EID vacation. even I was codding on Eid day. But my faculty wasn't accepted my project proposal. This is very sad for me.  I feel today to much nurvace. But I must complete this project in future. But there is one thing, I got you. I got the best person with a great attitude. And we are done a good conversation also.  Thanks, man. Wish you, may your dreams come true. All the best for your project/s and Pray for my successes also.

Comment: @Md.MarufBillah Hello. sorry for delayed response, i didn't got notification. my suggestion is just take it easy and relax :p don't get sad or mad for such things. if you drop college now, nothing special will happen, you can just find another way to your success.

Comment: @Md.MarufBillah And sorry about i said i can't help. that was because stackoverflow is good for question / answer. and me and others will be happy to answer your questions. but questions like : "how to create youtube" or "how to create a menu for my youtube" , etc are not suitable for here. you should know whats going on, and then start ask questions. that's why i suggested you to start learning javascript. anyway, your welcome and wish best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Codepen: [Link](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/qGzdva)

using `target.appendChild(el)` will move el to target. using `target.appendChild(el.cloneNode())` will copy el to target.

so use: 
`document.getElementById("fri11").appendChild(document.getElementById(dataM).cloneNode(true))`

---

there is some small problems in your code. `dataM` is id, so you cant clone it directly. you should first get it and then clone it.